# mySQL to PostgreSQL conversion (particular query)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Query below is working fine both in mySQL and Oracle:

```
select * from (
(select distinct msg_key from lct_messages where msg_step = 2) x,
(select distinct msg_step from lct_messages where msg_next_step = 3) y
)
```

Its purpose is to get two values in one row in separate columns. Can you help me in transforming this query to the one that will be working in Postgres?

When I run the one below I receive error:

```
SELECT (
(SELECT DISTINCT "MSG_KEY" FROM LCT_MESSAGES WHERE "MSG_STEP" = 2) x,
(SELECT DISTINCT "MSG_STEP" FROM LCT_MESSAGES WHERE "MSG_NEXT_STEP" = 3) y
)
```

Regards
Michal

Comment: And what is the error you get? Let me guess: "*subquery in FROM must have an alias*"?

Comment: in what way do the values of X relate to the values of Y? If you want them on the same row -- in separate columns -- then they have to be related in some way

Comment: one moment. I am preparing answer to your questions.

Comment: These two values not necesarly are taken from the same row in table lct_messages. What they share in common is parameter that they receive:

Comment: $sql = pg_query_params ($db, $query, 
 array(   $_POST['STEP']
  ,$_POST['STEP'])

Comment: ERROR:  error in syntax near "x"
LINE 2: ...ISTINCT "MSG_KEY" FROM LCT_MESSAGES WHERE "MSG_STEP" = 2) x,
                                                                     ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: error in syntax near "x"

Stan SQL: 42601
Character: 81

Comment: The thing is, if you don't relate them in any way, you're going to have a cartesian product between X and Y. Ie. if query aliased as X returns 3 rows, and your query aliased Y returns 4 rows, output would be 12 rows total; each row of X will go side by side with each row of Y, repeated (because you're not relating X w/ Y).

Comment: @BrianDeMilia That's not correct in this case. If the either of the subqueries returns more than one result, the query will fail. *("ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression")*

Comment: @cdhowie http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ad5c/1/0

Comment: @BrianDeMilia The conclusion from this is not that the query is bad, but that MySQL allows you to execute nonsensical queries.  (I can't imagine what bizarre logic it uses to turn that query into a cross join...)  PostgreSQL chokes on that query with a syntax error, because it *doesn't make any damn sense.*

Comment: Please provide essential information like the error message in the question, do not hide it in comments. [**Edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25275136/edit) your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra pair of parens in there.  This combines the two results into one single result column of type `record`, and the syntax to create a record object does not allow defining aliases of the record columns like that<sup>1</sup>.  This is why it chokes on the `x` with a syntax error.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT DISTINCT "MSG_KEY" FROM LCT_MESSAGES WHERE "MSG_STEP" = 2) x,
    (SELECT DISTINCT "MSG_STEP" FROM LCT_MESSAGES WHERE "MSG_NEXT_STEP" = 3) y;
```

This works correctly for me given a simple dummy table:

```
$ WITH LCT_MESSAGES ("MSG_KEY", "MSG_STEP", "MSG_NEXT_STEP") AS (VALUES
    ('a', 1, 2),
    ('b', 2, 3),
    ('c', 3, 4)
)
SELECT
    (SELECT DISTINCT "MSG_KEY" FROM LCT_MESSAGES WHERE "MSG_STEP" = 2) x,
    (SELECT DISTINCT "MSG_STEP" FROM LCT_MESSAGES WHERE "MSG_NEXT_STEP" = 3) y;

 x | y
---+---
 b | 2
(1 row)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See [section 8.15.2 "Composite Value Input" of the PostgreSQL 9.1 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/rowtypes.html) for a description of the syntax you were inadvertently using: *"The `ROW` expression syntax can also be used to construct composite values. ... The ROW keyword is actually optional as long as you have more than one field in the expression ..."*  So what it was seeing was equivalent to this:

```
SELECT ROW(
    (SELECT DISTINCT ...) x,
    (SELECT DISTINCT ...) y
);
```

And the `x` is indeed invalid syntax in this kind of expression.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much. My mistakes: to many '(' and no need for '* from'